# Setting ReadOnly Strings without Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, readonly

I'm working on an application that requires access to public strings.
However, I also wish to restrict write access. Since I have many strings, I want to avoid having a getter and private setter for each.

See code below:

```
public readonly string privateMem, peakVM, peakPaged, pagedSysMem, pagedMem, nonpagedSysMem;

    public override void Capture()
    {
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {

            // Throws error as privateMem can't be assigned a value

            privateMem = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024);
            peakVM = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakVirtualMemorySize64 / 1024);
            peakPaged = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakPagedMemorySize64 / 1024);
            pagedSysMem = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024);
            pagedMem = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedMemorySize64 / 1024);
            nonpagedSysMem = string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024);
        }

    }
```

I know there are ways to assign a value to readonly fields with reflection, however I've gathered from several other stackoverflow questions that this is a terrible idea.

So in conclusion:

1.
How can I assign a value to readonly strings without reflection, or does a better solution exist without using verbose getters and setters?

2.
Is there a way to declare a variable, assign it a value, and then designate it as readonly?

Comment: In what world are getters and setters "verbose"?  It seems like you're coding yourself in a corner

Comment: This would require a getter and setter for every string:

public string myString {
 get;
 private set;
}

If one had a lot of strings, getters and setters are cumbersome

Comment: Are these strings set more than once at runtime? Then you're going to need the `{get; private set;}` or choose a different language.

Comment: @KeyserSoze there are key distinctions between fields and properties, particularly when dealing with access.  So if you intend to do this sort of thing in C#, you'll need to stick with setters and getters.

Comment: Many strings are many strings are many strings. If that is a problem then that is the problem.

Comment: I just need to declare the strings as public and then assign them a value at a later time. I'm thinking a ReadOnlyDictionary might be a possible solution.

Comment: On top of the comments above, visual studio has a code snippet for properties (prop) that makes writing them trivial and only require a few keystrokes. You could write your own code snippet for a property with a private setter to save even more time. Or there's always the tried and true copy and paste.

Comment: if you're setting them from the constructor, you don't even need `private set`. You can just declare `{get;}` and everything will work just peachy.

Comment: In the time you've asked this question and waited for answers you could already have finished a clean class with getters and private setters.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the question isn't asked from a purely pragmatic perspective. I agree entirely with you and everyone else that I could use getters and private setters. Granted, I also feel like there are other theoretical approaches to what may be a purely theoretical problem.

Comment: Most folks here would not call it a 'theoretical' problem but an 'imaginary' one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current answer of using a dictionary is incorrect, since it is not readonly.

A more correct approach is to initialize an `IReadOnlyDictionary` (in .NET 4.5 or later) instance based off of the dictionary once and add logic to prevent it from being overwritten with new values once initialized.

By utilizing a backing field, we can ensure that even if an attempt to modify it occurs inside of the class, it cannot be overwritten once it contains values.

```
private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _memoryStrings;
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> memoryStrings
{
    get
    {
        return _memoryStrings;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (_memoryStrings != null && _memoryStrings.Count() > 0) return;
        _memoryStrings = value;
    }
}

public void Capture()
{
    if (memoryStrings == null || memoryStrings.Count() == 0)
    {
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            memoryStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"privateMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024)},
                {"peakVm", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakVirtualMemorySize64 / 1024)},
                {"peakPaged", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakPagedMemorySize64 / 1024)},
                {"pagedSysMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024)},
                {"pagedMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedMemorySize64 / 1024)},
                { "nonpagedSysMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024)}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This gives us multiple levels of immutability.

If you call `Capture()` multiple times, it will only run the calculations the first time.

If you attempt to overwrite the dictionary elsewhere in the class, it will not be overwritten once it contains values.

If you attempt to overwrite a property or add a value once the collection is created, you'll either receive a compile time exception (in the case of using an indexer or attempting to use the `.Add()` method) or a runtime exception (in the case of using the `.Add()` method via casting to `IDictionary`).

Comment: Brilliant explanation and implementation, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to do makes no sense. Readonly fields can only be populated inside a constructor. They are very useful for Dependency Injection for example, things are set only inside a constructor and that's it, can't be modified outside of it.

You can always use a private set for example. Saying that getters and setters are "verbose" makes no sense either. They are there for a reason. Trying to find a way to do things in a different way will more than likely mean crazy code and all that just to avoid using a simple setter?

Think what you are doing and why and then finally ask yourself, is it really worth it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a dictionary. This way I only need one getter and private setter, and it's much more scalable for adding more strings/system info later on.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> memoryStrings
         {
             get;
             private set;
         }

        public MemoryUsageFragment() {
            memoryStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public override void Capture()
        {
            using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                memoryStrings.Add("privateMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024));
                memoryStrings.Add("peakVm", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakVirtualMemorySize64 / 1024));
                memoryStrings.Add("peakPaged", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PeakPagedMemorySize64 / 1024));
                memoryStrings.Add("pagedSysMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024));
                memoryStrings.Add("pagedMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.PagedMemorySize64 / 1024));
                memoryStrings.Add("nonpagedSysMem", string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 / 1024));
            }    
        }
```

Comment: private set is only allowing the dictionary to be set privately. Users will still be able to add/remove from the dictionary publicly.  The strings aren't readonly. You could create a method which returns a string based on the key passed in, and make the dictionary a private field.

Comment: Very valid point. And the method idea would work, however I'm binding a WPF ListBox to memoryStrings, and want to preserve that functionality if at all possible

Comment: @KeyserSoze please see my answer on how to work around the issues with your current Dictionary implementation

Answer (score -1):

```
public string privateMem        { get; private set; }
public string peakVM            { get; private set; }
public string peakPaged         { get; private set; }
public string pagedSysMem       { get; private set; }
public string pagedMem          { get; private set; }
public string nonpagedSysMem    { get; private set; }
```

This took all of about 20 seconds. What's verbose about that?

Comment: is this really an answer?

Comment: Sure is. Not my fault his question was flawed. But this code will solve his problem without needlessly complicating his code.

Comment: As you can see from his comments, he knows how to write properties. He's just too stubborn to. So basically your answer is just showing how fast YOU can write code/properties. Nothing useful was added by this. -1.

Comment: Do as you wish with your downvote, but the purpose is to answer his question. There is no better way, and as Andrei pointed out in his answer, what he's trying to do doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Sylverac, I understand getters and setters, and I understand that they are a pragmatic way to handle this problem given the current number of strings. But consider in the future, I want to add more strings and get more system information to display to the screen, or even format them nicely with wpf. Getters and setters on each string would become cumbersome. Something more akin to a collection might provide better functionality, and I wouldn't consider that needless complication.